# Partitioning the vertex set of a graph with a large independent set

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph on an even number of vertices, say $2M$. Assume that the largest independent set in $G$ has at most $M$ elements. Is it true that there exists a set of $2m$ vertices (for some $m\leq M$), say $v_1,v_2,\ldots, v_{2m}$, with the following three properties:

1) The induced subgraph on $v_1,\ldots,v_{m-1}$ is an independent set;

2) The induced subgraph on $v_m,\ldots,v_{2m}$ is a clique;

3) Removing these $2m$ vertices from $G$ leaves a graph with no independent set larger than M-m.

**It turned out that the claim is not true and Colin provided a counterexample - a cycle on five vertices and an isolated vertex.**

**A less precise question**. Under the same condition - a graph $G$ on $2M$ vertices with no independent set larger than $M$ - could we say something about the structure of $G$ like:

a) $G$ is has a very particular form (say an independent set on $M-1$ vertices and a clique on $M+1$ vertices);

b) Otherwise we can partition the vertex set of into part with even number of vertices (say $2m_i$) so that the induced subgraphs on these sets of vertices have each no independent set larger than $m_i$?

Comment: If we could have such a statement, maybe we could say something more about these small graphs? That is, maybe they could have a very simple structure like a cycle on an odd number of vertices and an isolated edge?

Comment: You say $M=3$ works - what about a cycle of length $5$ + one isolated vertex?

Comment: Colin, then take $m=1$ and remove two vertices, one of which is the isolated vertex.

Comment: (I am assuming TOM means $v_1,\ldots, v_m$ are a stable set and $v_{m+1},\ldots,v_{2m}$ are a clique.  Is that the case?)

Comment: No, I meant exactly what I said - m-1 vertices forming an independent set, and m+1 vertices forming a clique. 

I just wanted to add one more assumption - assume that the initial graph immediately has an independent set of size exactly M. Otherwise the 3-partite Turan graph gives a counterexample for the claim I want. 

Comment: Hi TOM.  May I ask why you decided to edit the original question?  I think the original formulation was a bit clearer.  This one is equivalent (I view it as the natural induction approach to the original question).  Cheers.

Comment: Dear Tony, 
I have found I counterexample for that formulation and changed the formulation into a weaker statement.

Comment: In that case, doesn't Colin provide a valid counterexample?

Comment: Dear TOM.  It seems to me that the current statement is not weaker than the original one.  That is, if the current statement is true, then by induction on $M$, the original statement is true.  Note that condition (3) is equivalent to saying that the after removing these $2m$ vertices we get a graph with independence number *exactly* $M-m$, since the $2m+1$ from the clique contains at most one vertex from any independent set.  

Comment: Dear all, Colin's counterexample indeed works! I will try to formulate the "right" question. Thank you all for the help!